# How to prove that the map $T:\mathbb{R}_0^+ \times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ define a semi dynamic system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Lets suppose that for each $(0,x_0)\in \mathbb{R}_0^+ \times \mathbb{R}^n$ there is an unique maximal solution $\phi=\phi(s,x_0)$ of the IVP $x'=f(x)$, $x(0)=x_0$ that passes through that point and this solution is defined over $[0,\infty)$.

Prove that the map

\begin{equation*}
T:\mathbb{R}_0^+ \times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n\\
(t,x_0)\mapsto T(t)(x_0):=\phi(t,x_0)
\end{equation*}

define a semi dynamic system in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have proven that

- $T(0)(x_0)=x_0$
- $T(s+t)(x_0)=T(s)T(t)(x_0)$

But I don't know hot to prove that the map

\begin{equation*}
T:\mathbb{R}_0^+ \times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n\\
(t,x)\mapsto T(t)(x):=\phi(t,x)
\end{equation*}

is continuous. Those three conditions define a semi dynamic system.

when I take two points $(t,x)$ and $(s,y)$, then I must show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\|(t,x)-(s,y)\|<\epsilon$ then $\|\phi(t,x)-\phi(s,y)\|<\epsilon$. But I don't know how to reach this result.

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Do you have to prove it from scratch? It 's a fairly standard result that solutions of a differential equation depend continously on the initial condition.

Comment: Also, what are your hypothesis on $f$?

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta I have to prove it from scratch. But again, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net There is no more info about $f$, sorry.

Comment: I think $f$ being locally Lipschitz continuous should be enough for everything. Anyway you want such an assumption so that there is a unique solution.

Comment: I agree with Olivier. If the maximal solution is not unique, then the result doesn't hold.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta I made a mistake writing the problem, in fact "there is a unique maximal solution", I am so sorry.